# php function doesn't return a value

Tags: php, xampp, php-5.3, php-5.2, php-safe-mode

I have a class which works fine with php 5.3 (XAMPP 1.7.3, windows 7) but doesn't work in my server(php 5.2.17 - Safe mode **On**):

```
 <?php

    class MYSQL_DB {

        var $connection;

        function MYSQL_DB() {
            $this->connection = mysql_connect(S, U, P) or die('Can\'t connect to MySQL server.');
            mysql_select_db(DB, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        function getJobs($wid) {
            $q = "SELECT * FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "joblist where owner = {$wid} order by ID ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
            $ret = $this->mysql_fetch_all($result);
            mysql_free_result($result);
            return $ret;
        }

        function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
            $all = array();
            if ($result) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $all[] = $row;
                }
                return $all;
            }
        }

    }
    $db=new MYSQL_DB();

?>
```

And in another file, I used `getjobs` function:

```
<?php
    $tempbJobs=$db->getJobs(1368);
    var_dump($tempbJobs);
?>
```

when I use `var_dump`  right before `return $ret;` in `getjobs` function, it shows me correct values, but `var_dump($tempbJobs);`  will print **NULL**.

P.S: I simplified the code, it works on my localhost but not on production server.
P.S: If I change `return $ret;`  to `return 'DUMPED';` , returned value would be `string(6) "DUMPED"`

`var_dump($ret );`  output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "10755"
    ["owner"]=>
    string(5) "23626"
    ["field"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["expi"]=>
    string(10) "1372144648"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "10756"
    ["owner"]=>
    string(5) "23626"
    ["field"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["expi"]=>
    string(10) "1372144654"
  }
}
```

Comment: does your production server has data?

Comment: @DevZer0 Yes, it has. As I said: if I use `var_dump` right before `return $ret;` in `getjobs` function, it shows me correct values.

Comment: @FDL thanks but I know that.

Comment: What happens if you change `return $ret` to something specific like `return 'working'`, do you get a return value then?

Comment: You are calling `getjobs` or `getJobs` method?

Comment: @OmarSharif both definition and usage are using same letters!

Comment: Could you show us the array you generate when you use `var_dump` right before `return $ret;`? If the string returns fine I can only think there is some issue with the array being generated, but god knows why seeing as your code looks fine..

Comment: What's the difference between what we're looking at and the real unsimplified code?

Comment: @FDL I added var_dump's output to question,

Comment: @dale Actually nothing, i just removed other functions

Comment: I can't fathom this out, the code looks sound to me

Comment: None of the functions you are using are involved with `Safe mode On`, but since you explicitly mention it. Does it work when safe mode is off? Also I would minify the code even further to find the problem. Instead of changing `return $red` to `return 'test'`, try `$red = 10` just before the return statement. Does it show 10? If so, try to remove the free result. Or dont use set `$red= $this->mysql_fetch_all($result);` but just use `return $this->mysql_fetch_all($result);`. Also dont set `$tempbJobs` but just `var_dump($db->getJobs(1368));`. Remove as much code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you only return $all from the function mysql_fetch_all($result) if $result is true I have to assume that the mysql_query() is returning false.

After the call to

```
$result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
```

Can you add this

```
$result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo "ErrorNo: " . mysql_errno() . " Error Message: " . mysql_error();
}
```

This might help identify what the problem actually is as it has to be a database error of some sort.

Comment: Thanks but as I said I used `var_dump` on `$ret`  and it was fine! the only problem is no value is returned!

Comment: Yes... but if you read what I said, the only way to get NO VALUE is if the execution of the query i.e. mysql_query() returns an error. If that happens $result will be FALSE.... the test in mysql_fetch_all will never execute the return statement.... so it will return NULL the default for a function that does not execute a return; ....And you will get NULL or in your tems NO VALUE. So therefore THE QUERY HAS AN ERROR. To be honest I cant see why you need the curly brackets around the parameter $wid i.e. {$wid}.

Comment: I agree -- try to return empty array -- move `return $all` one bracket `}` further.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check that your constants `S, U, P, TB_PREFIX` are `defined()` and they have values.

Also modify your function `mysql_fetch_all` to return response anyway:

```
function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
    $all = array();
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $all[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed all your comments.
In one of your comments you said that return is not working but I think it is working properly because you already said in one of your comments that when you print out the result before `return $ret` it gives you the correct result.

**fact :** `mysql_fetch_all($result)` also returning result.

checkout the sql code : `$q = "SELECT * FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "joblist where owner = {$wid} order by ID ASC";`  I do not know {$wid} what it is.

Test it

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "joblist where owner = '$wid' order by ID ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

try after defining array for $ret in the function getjobs()

```
$ret=array(); //try
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit rusty question but yet still interesting. Are you able to found solution on that ?

If same code doesn't work on different server i would have suspected in that case memory limit. Try to increase php memory limit.

And it could be wise to check phpinfo(); on both servers to compare differences.

Comment: I gave up on this! as you can see, there is no accepted answer!